# Avalonia UI, Why should I specify DPI when creating a Bitmap Image and how should I do it

Tags: avaloniaui

By what I know DPI is only appropriate in the context of describing quality of output device, in which describes how dense does pixels distribute on the plane of monitor or printed paper. But how does it make sense that I need to pass in an argument specifying DPI when calling constructor of WriteableBitmap.

I tried looking at property of an image file in my computer, it only has information of size, width * height in unit of pixel, and how many bit does each pixel take. That suggests image file itself don't need DPI information to be displayed on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this today, and... it's unintuitive, to say the least.

You might think OK, it's DPI, it's specifically about real world measurements instead of screen pixels, so e.g. 100px at 50 DPI will take up 2 inches in the real world. Alas, it works *the other way around*. If it just so happens to be, it *might* even show up as 2 inches on your screen - but then if you change the bitmap to 20 DPI, it will be shown *smaller* than before.

So the setting on the image file means something like *"the DPI Avalonia pretends **your device** has while rendering the image"*... Anyway, you can search for fitting values by putting a coloured border around an image you know the size of, e.g. if you use

```xml
<Border Background="Crimson" Width="100" Height="100" >
    <Image Source="MyImage.bmp"/>
</Border>
```

with a 100x100px image file, and your DPI is too small, you will see the red background overlap.

The right value for me was 96 DPI (`Vector.One * 96`). IIRC that's a Windows standard of sorts, so no idea if this will be broken on other operating systems.